# I have several functions and how I know which one is the maximum in a certain range?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

What I did are the followings

These lines will generate a piecewise function pw which tells me the corresponding variable given an interval as follows:

[image]

Now, I want to get:

1. names of variable instead of value of variable, such as "question 1" instead of "9.9-10beta" given "beta<=0.98092"
2. width of each interval, that is: 0.980392, (0.993289-0.980392=)0.012897, and (2-0.993289=)1.00671

I thank you very much for providing the answer or some hints!

Comment: Please post your code instead of the picture so we can test it easily.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution to Question Part 1

**Option 1:** "Which one is the largest function within the range?"

```
ClearAll["question*"];

questions = {{question1, 9.9-10\[Beta]}, {question2, 4.9-4.9\[Beta]},
             {question3, -9.9+10\[Beta]}, {question4, -4.9+4.9\[Beta]}};

questions[[pos=Extract[
             Position[#, Max@#]& @ 
             (  Maximize[{#, 0<\[Beta]<2}, \[Beta]]& /@ 
                         questions[[All, 2]]  )[[All, 1]],
             {1, 1}]]]

(* {question3, -9.9+10\[Beta]} *)
```

### Explanation

1. `ClearAll["question*"]` makes sure, that no `question<whatsoever>` is defined anymore.
2. `question = ...` defines a list of (now undefined) symbols paired with the definition of the function.
3. `question[[...]]` gets a pair from this list, i.e.: The result. Which one is decided within the brackets.
4. Via `Maximize`, the functions' maxima within the given range `0<\[Beta]<2` are evaluated.
5. `Position` retrieves the index of the "largest" function as determined by `Maximize` by comparing each result to the overall maximum value.  `pos` is saved for later use in the answer to Part 2 of your question.
6. Finally, `Extract` just gets rid of unnecessary lists surrounding the resulting index.

Since the `question<whatsoever>s` are undefined, the result is just a pair from the `question` list, giving you the "name" of the maximum within the range for `\[Beta]` you defined.

**Option 2:** "Rewrite the `Piecewise`, so that there are no functions, but the functions' names!"

```
pw /. Map[Symbol@#->#&, Table["question" <> ToString@i, {i, Range@4}]]
```

## Solution to Question Part 2

Depending on what you are after, there are two possibilities:

**Option 1:** Determine the interval widths in by ascending value of `\[Beta]`, which can e.g. be done as follows (based on the result yielded by the maximum index `pos` from Part 1 of your question):

```
Differences@Sort[Part[
              Quiet@Reduce[#, \[Beta]] & /@
              (
                 questions[[pos, 2]]>questions[[#, 2]]& /@
                 Delete[Range@Length@questions, pos]
              ), 
              All, 2]]
(* {0.00960784, 0.00328859} *)
```

This uses `Reduce` to determine the conditions, at which `\[Beta]` the largest of the functions (as determined in Part 1) actually *is* larger than all each of the others. This conditions are then extracted, sorted and the differences calculated and returned. The `Quiet` is not really required, but suppresses the messages resulting from `Reduce` not really liking floating point input.

**Option 2:** Retrieve the (one) interval value from your `Piecewise` representation:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Select[
    Flatten@
      Cases[pw,
            (Less|LessEqual|Greater|GreaterEqual|Inequality)
              [a___, \[Beta], b___] :> {a, b},
            Infinity], 
     NumericQ]//Differences
(* {0.0128964} *)
```

I hope this helps!

P.S.: Please post code in the future, not screenshots. This would make our efforts to help you *much* easier.

---

Besides:

You use nested `Max`, but this can be simplified, since `Max` takes any number of arguments, so this would be sufficient (and is much less tedious to write ;) ):

```
pw=PiecewiseExpand[Max[question1,question2,question3,question4],
                   Assumptions->0<\[Beta]<2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, Jinxed. 
On your solution to Part 1, how can I get the full list? for this example, I was expecting to get {question1, question2, question3} as the function which enters pw; 

On your solution to Part 2, I could not run through. I run the solution to Part 1 first and then copy and run the second part, but error message is:
Part::pspec: "Part specification {{3}} is neither an integer nor a list of integers. "

I was aware of "nested max" issue, but when I used "nested max" instead of a single max, it can work our all the time. 
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @WendyWen: I misplaced the `pos` assignment in the first code example. Is fixed now. I also added another option to the solution to your first question, which replaces the formulae with the functions' names (by doing simple string replacement). Take a look! Nested `Max` should behave no different than only one `Max` with >2 arguments, no?

Comment: I like your option for the first question, but can it be more flexible? what if the names are "James" "Kate""Gerry" instead of Question1,2,3? On Sol to the second part, it works now but it does not generate correct results, doesn't it? I was expecting to get 0.980392, (0.993289-0.980392=)0.012897, and (2-0.993289=)1.00671. Thanks.